# Is it possible to display array values iteratively in a panel using VB6

Tags: vb6

I'm new to vb6 and need to display object array values in a panel. Each object is included as an array element and each object contains many attributes. Each attribute of an object needs to display in a panel. Data Grid can be used to achieve this. There are many samples available on the internet to display database tables in a data grid. Is it possible to display array of objectes in data grid instead of database table.

Comment: You need to add a lot more specific details and focus on exactly what you are stuck on. The way this is written now it sounds like a "do my work for me" question.

Answer (score 0):

The tricky part is to dynamically enumerate the objects' properties. It *can* be done with certain restrictions. See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656471/how-can-i-list-the-properties-of-an-object-programmatically-in-vb6) for a good starting point.